# How to test Collapsible panels using calabash-android

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

I have 2 collapsible panels on application page and I want to verify if I open one of them and after some seconds I click on other panel then first one collapse, the way this function works I want to automate the test that when i open any panel the other panel should collapse.
How do I test this? 
Not able to find suitable on Calabash-Android forums

Thanks in advance
Vaibhav

Comment: What exactly is causing you the problems? Is it that you want to make it random which one is clicked first? If you query for collapsible, check the state of each, then touch of of them and after that verify the state of both/all then I think you should get what you are looking for.

Comment: Would you not test as follows? Open the first panel, check to see if it is open.  Touch the second panel. Assert that only the new panel is now open.